# Disabling the drag image in QListView

Tags: qt, drag, qlistview

Is it possible to disable the drag pixmap when dragging an item/icon from a QListView.

My application performs custom rendering of the dragged item when hovering it above the view. However, since I have ported my application to Qt5 the dragged item of a list view seems to always show the decoration role during the drag operation. I would like to disable this, since my custom rendering is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you want, but if you want to disable the drag pixmap you can just set an empty pixmap in the startDrag method i.e.

```
drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
# Create empty mimedata just to initilize the Qdrag.
mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
mimeData.setData("text/plain", "")
drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
# Empty pixmap. No drag icon
drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
...
drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's indeed how to set this up when manually initiating the drag operation. However, when using the list view it will be default take care of initiating the drag operation (in QIconModeViewBase::filterStartDrag). And in there it always seems to set the pixmap. Is there way to change this list view behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QListWidget.setMovement()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#movement-prop) function. The function takes [`QListView::Movement movement`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#Movement-enum), and `QListView.Static` disables the moving of icons.

Here is an example of codes from pyqt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class DisableMoving(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.list_widget = QListWidget(self)
        self.list_widget.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.list_widget.setFlow((QListView.LeftToRight))
        self.list_widget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        # setMovement
        self.list_widget.setMovement(QListView.Static)

        item_1 = QListWidgetItem()
        item_1.setIcon(QIcon('1.jpg'))
        self.list_widget.addItem(item_1)

        item_2 = QListWidgetItem()
        item_2.setIcon(QIcon('2.jpg'))
        self.list_widget.addItem(item_2)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Disable icon moving')
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = DisableMoving()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```